# Integrating custom HTML5/iframe widgets into Facebook Timeline / Tab Pages

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, widget

- I have a widget that users can already integrate into their websites via an HTML/iframe code that my app generates.
- I would like the users to be able to place the widget into their Facebook Company Pages.
- The widgets are available via `https://example.com/widget/XXXXXXXXXX/` where `XXXXXXXXXX` is the unique ID of the user that build/generated the widget.
- According to [Page Tab Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs) my Page Tab can only have one URL that can be served to user but if I place there `https://example.com/widget/1111111111/` then all users will see the widget of User #`1111111111` if I place there `https://example.com/widget/` then I do now know how to provide the proper User ID when [first adding the Page Tab](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page).

I would like to know what's the easiest way for users to add timeline boxes / page tabs with either the iframe code I provide or by adding the page tab via the dialog and providing the User ID as well (maybe via a direct link from my website that already contains the user_id in the parameter request). If possible I would like to NOT use any Facebook APIs/etc since the widget works independently and does not require any facebook data, I would simply want the widget to be displayed on users' Facebook timelines/pages wherever they would like to display it.

Thanks!

Comment: The `signed_request` parameter that gets POSTed to your app on initial load into the iframe contains the page id when embedded as a page tab. On normal user timelines, you can not place any “widgets” or apps at all.

Comment: @CBroe yes, thanks! I noticed the `signed_request ` but to use that I would need to  remember the `page_id` when the app is first installed (and sent back to me via redirect parameter `tabs_added`) and associate it with the `user_id` on my end? I.e. there's no way to make the tab remember some kind of ID (unique URL?) during the installation which it will always be sent? This would simplify many things and I wouldn't have to create any associations in the database.

Comment: Why do you need to associate it with a user id anyway, if it is going to be used on a _page_? Shouldn’t the content you show be related to the page, rather than the user? What if the user manages multiple pages, and installs your app on more than one of them? Anyway, the page id is the only thing you’ll get, if you need to associate that with anything else, then you have to do it on your end.

Comment: It's not really associated with user_id, it's associated with a business_id of a Business that the user manages on my site, I tried to simplify my case so it's easier to explain but I guess that made things more confusing. Anyway, I am doing the association with `page_id` which is included in the `signed_request` so I will render different content depending on that value. Thanks for your help and I'll accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request) parameter that gets POSTed to your app on initial load into the iframe contains the page id when embedded as a page tab.

If you need to identify the page that your app is embedded on, and/or associate any more data with it, that is your way to go.

How to parse it, is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games#parsingsr